# Comando no Powershel de extrair dados

Tags: powershell

Boa noite,

Eu preciso de uma ajuda. Na minha aplicação, vou utilizar no powershell o comando $env:computername para exibir o hostname. Suponha que o hostname que ele exibiu foi CCC_DESKTOP. Eu preciso por gentileza de um comando, que extraia somente os 3 primeiros dígitos, que no caso é CCC.

Comment: Use `$env:computername.split('_')[0]` e retorna o que vem antes do `_` == `CCC`

Answer (score -3):

Basta usar substring:

$env:computername.substring(0,3)